# Не передаёт данные в массив

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть массив которые передаёт данные, но когда запускаю скрипт, в переменных ничего нету

```
$data = '[{"id": "'.$phone.'", "name": "'.$name.'", "phone": "'.$phone.'"}]';

$name = "test551";

$phone = "870749745443";


                        [id] => 
                        [name] => 
                        [phone] =>
```

Comment: Конкретно в этом случае вы объявляете переменные ПОСЛЕ того, как их используете. Перенесите объявление переменных до формирования массива `$data`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

То что у вас в переменной $data скорее всего json. Делаешь так

```
$array = json_decode($data);
$array[] = $name;
```

Тогда В переменной $array будет массив и туда запишите переменную $name